# Visual Studio Code - Not able to upload nuget packge that is created locally on my computer

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-code, nuget-package

So I have written two programs(Main program and Calculatorlib) on Visual Studio Code where I have created package locally for one of the programs(Caluclatorlib)by using the command dotnet pack.
The package Calculatorlib_package.3.0.0.nupkg is created locally. 
However I want to upload this package on visual studio code from my local computer so that I can give Package Reference to Main program.

I don't see any options to upload this on visual studio code. 
But in Visual studio I see there is an option called "Manage Nuget packages" where we can go and upload locally created packages.
Can someone guide me how to do this?

Comment: There is no UI element to guide you, so you have to use command line, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli#publish-the-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your local package location as a Nuget package source. You should be able to add a Nuget package source using the package configuration , and add the location of the directory when you have the Nuget package locally.